# Iterating over an array in an ExtJS Template

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I am using ExtJS to apply a set of data from a AJAx call to an `Ext.Template`. One of the elements is an array of strings.

```
var data = {
  name: "I am Here!",
  messages: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
};
```

I've defined the template like this

```
var tpl = new Ext.Template(
  '<h2>{name}</h2>',
  '<tpl for="{messages}">',
    '<p>{.}</p>',
  '</tpl>'
);
```

When I apply this template to the data, it shows the `{.}` literally instead of printing each element. Most of the searches I have done for using arrays in in ExtJS use this format. Here is the JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u4zkM/2/

What is wrong with the way I am trying to use the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays and other advanced functionality you need to use Ext.XTemplate.  Also remove the brackets around messages.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<h2>{name}</h2>',
    '<tpl for="messages">',
        '<p>{.}</p>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zkM/3/)